# ajax вместо вывода переменной дублируется кнопка

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

нужно отправить две JS переменных в пхп, а потом считать из него ответ
но у меня он отправляет переменные, а в ответ - дублируется кнопка

как поправить?

```js
< meta charset = "UTF-8" >
  <
  script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" > < /script>

  <
  button type = "button"
id = "post-btn" > Submit < /button> <
  div id = "parent" > < b > Старое содержимое < /b></div >

  <
  script >
  $a = "777";
$b = "888";
$("#post-btn").click(function() {
  $.post($($a, $b).find('input').serialize(), function(data) {
    $mydata = (data);
    document.getElementById('parent').innerHTML = $mydata;
  });
}); <
/script>

файл 10. php

  <?php
$username=$_POST["a"];
$password=$_POST["b"];
$qwe = $username . $password;
echo "User: ".$qwe;
?>
```

Comment: `как поправить?` - убрать код `php` в совершенно другой файл где не будет ни html ни js, а только php и  обращаться к нему

Comment: это и так сделано. я эе подписал *файл 10. php*

Comment: php не может ну никак ответом отдавать еще и кнопку вдобавок, если только эта самая кнопка не находится в этом же файле. Либо ты не всё показываешь

Answer (score -1):

```js
 $a = "777";
$b = "888";
$("#post-btn").click(function(e) {
  $.post("10.php", { a: $a, b :$b }, function(data) {
    $mydata = (data);
    $('#parent').html($mydata);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type = "button"
id = "post-btn"> Submit </button> <div id = "parent"> <b> Старое содержимое </b></div>
```